# Resizing image interactively in gimp?

Tags: gimp

Can image be resized interactively, e.g. by dragging the mouse, in gimp? All I know is to select menu and type in some size number that I would like to resize the image to. Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, you can.
There is a scale tool in the side menu(SHIFT-T).
To learn more about this tool see: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html